# sum of values in input boxes using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a **form that takes values from a hash** and creates three input boxes(having **class** amount, acNo,debNo) per key **name attribute** combination of the hash value and a string **bed** in my case now i am trying to get the sum of the values in input boxes having "bed" in their name and have class "amount".

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 alert('document is loaded');
    $("input[name*='bed'][class='amount']").each(function() {//doen't go in this loop

        alert('in the bed'); //no alert
            $(this).keyup(function(){

                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("input[name*='bed'][class='amount']").each(function() { 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("input[name='totalBEDamount']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

I am using the above jquery to get sum of values. The problem is that it works fine as fixed layout [fixed layout fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/XyN7m/) but when i am creating the document on radio button selection from a hash the code [fiddle with error](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/3KHmh/1/) doesn't work? Why???

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[class='amount']` and use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)** (for your **dynamically created elements**) in place of `[class='column']` like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('keyup',"input[name*='bed'][class='amount']", function () {
         var sum = 0;
         //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
         $("input[name*='bed'][class='amount']").each(function () {
             //add only if the value is number
             if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                 sum += parseFloat(this.value);
             }

         });
         $("input[name='totalBEDamount']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
     });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/JmZtp/)**

Comment: thanks a lot man...no need to say it worked. Yeah I made a mistake in class name but the real was that I was not using on() for dynamically created object.